# Introducing backslash and quote at beginning of string

Tags: ruby

I want to convert `"her"` to `"\"her"`.

I've tried using `insert` method:

```
>> "her".insert(0,'\"')
=> "\\"her"
```

and

```
>> "her".insert(0,'"')
=> ""her"
```

None of them gives me what I want: `"\"her"`

Comment: So you want `"\"her"` or `"\"her\""`?

Comment: Also, the result in your example doesn't look correct. The first should be `"\\\"her"`, the second should be `"\"her"`

Comment: Why not use `"\"#{var}\""` or `"\\\"#{var}\\\""`?

Comment: @MarekLipka: Sorry, first one. Edited.

Comment: @YuHao: That's what irb gave me. I didn't hard code it.

Comment: On my system (Ruby 2.1), irb shows `=> "\\\"her"` for the former and `=> "\"her"` for the latter example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"her".insert(0,'"')
```

actually returns `"\"her"`, which is what you said you wanted in the first place.

If you want to obtain `"\"her\""`, you might want to use [Object#inspect](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Object.html#method-i-inspect):

```
"her".inspect
=> "\"her\""
```

Or, you can simply concatenate quotes at the beginning and at the end:

```
'"' + "her" + '"'
=> "\"her\""
```

Comment: Executing what you proposed in the first place on irb gives me what I posted: `>> "her".insert(0,'"')
=> ""her"` Can this be version dependent?

Comment: @borjagvo Here it is in action: http://ideone.com/S8iRGS . Yes, my first example returns a quote only at the beginning. Check out the other two.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want `"\"her"`

```
a = "her".insert(0,'\"')
#=> "\\\"her"
puts a
#=> \"her
```

If you want output `"\"her\""`

```
a = "her"
#=> "her"
b = '\"'+a+'\"'
#=> "\\\"her\\\""
puts b
#=> \"her\"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is fine, you just don't know the meaning of `\\` in console.

The first `\` is escape character and second `\` is character itself.

You will see `\"her` in the text `foo.txt` as you expected by:

```
File.write("foo.txt", "her".insert(0,'\"'))
```